# Type Conformation Error: Iterable[Int] to expected type List[Int]

Tags: scala

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
  var minK = List.empty[Int]
  while(it.hasNext){
    val s = it.next()
    val sig = MH3.stringHash(s.srcId.toString, 0)
    val sig2 = MH3.stringHash(s.dstId.toString, 0)
    val e = minK:+sig:+sig2
    minK = bottom(100, e)
  }
```

The signature of the bottom function looks like this:

```
def bottom[T](n: Int, li: List[T])
           (implicit ord: Ordering[T]): Iterable[T]
```

I am getting an error at the last line of the code. The compiler is complaining that `Expression of type Iterable[Int] doesn't conform to expected type List[Int]`. But the type of `e` is `List[Int]`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type of `minK` is `List[Int]`, and function `bottom` returns `Iterable[Int]`.

Change first line to:

```
var minK = Iterable.empty[Int]
```

or use `toList`:

```
minK = bottom(100, e).toList
```

Comment: Ahh I missed that the error was associated with the variable `minK` rather than `e`. I think the second suggestion should be toList, right? not toIterable as I have edited.